# How to integrate a sqlite database into my c++ program that will store specified cin entries

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, sha256

I'm trying to combine C++ and SQLite to create a database for sha-256 hashes. I need the database to import, store and export sha-256 hashes and meanings. I already have the C++ program working. The program asks the user to create their own library if they want and I want the entries to be stored for all users. This will expand the library and make it more useful as its existence continues. I'm fairly new to cpp so the existing program is a bit basic. What I am looking for is a way to move variables from cpp to sqlite and any other steps necessary for a clean integration.
Thanks!
Below is the existing cpp and sqlite

```cpp
    //include libraries
    //Sorry,this is in a js compiler becuase i coulnd't figure out how to post it as cpp, the program itsellf works in cpp.
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {

      //if user wants to run this
      std::string yon;
      std::cout << "Type 'yes' to add 25 custom hashes to your library, type no to skip.\n";
      std::cin >> yon;
      
      if (yon == "yes") {

      //int var for user library
    std::string hash;
    std::string meaning;
    std::string hash1;
    std::string meaning1;
    std::string hash2;
    std::string meaning2;
    std::string hash3;
    std::string meaning3;
    std::string hash4;
    std::string meaning4;
    std::string hash5;
    std::string meaning5;
    std::string hash6;
    std::string meaning6;
    std::string hash7;
    std::string meaning7;
    std::string hash8;
    std::string meaning8;
    std::string hash9;
    std::string meaning9;
    std::string hash10;
    std::string meaning10;
    std::string hash11;
    std::string meaning11;
    std::string hash12;
    std::string meaning12;
    std::string hash13;
    std::string meaning13;
    std::string hash14;
    std::string meaning14;
    std::string hash15;
    std::string meaning15;
    std::string hash16;
    std::string meaning16;
    std::string hash17;
    std::string meaning17;
    std::string hash18;
    std::string meaning18;
    std::string hash19;
    std::string meaning19;
    std::string hash20;
    std::string meaning20;
    std::string hash21;
    std::string meaning21;
    std::string hash22;
    std::string meaning22;
    std::string hash23;
    std::string meaning23;
    std::string hash24;
    std::string meaning24;
    //var user library
    std::cout << "Do not restart this learning repository or else variables will be forgotten\n";
    std::cout << "Enter first hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash;
    std::cout << "Enter first meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash1;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning1;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash2;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning2;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash3;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning3;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash4;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning4;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash5;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning5;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash6;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning6;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash7;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning7;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash8;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning8;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash9;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning9;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash10;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning10;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash11;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning11;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash12;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning12;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash13;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning13;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash14;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning14;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash15;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning15;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash16;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning16;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash17;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning17;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash18;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning18;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash19;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning19;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash20;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning20;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash21;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning21;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash22;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning22;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash23;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning23;
    std::cout << "Enter hash\n";
    std::cin >> hash24;
    std::cout << "Enter meaning\n";
    std::cin >> meaning24;
    std::cout << "Done, returning to main program now!\n";

      //intilize variables and startup   
      std::string name;
      std::string securitykey = "Echoes";
      std::string usersecuritykey;
      std::cout << "Please enter the program security key\n (key = Echoes)\n";
      std::cin >> usersecuritykey;
    //security key 
      if (usersecuritykey == securitykey) {

        std::cout << "Please enter your name\n";
        std::cin >> name;
      std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", Input First Secure hash algorithm 256 hash to be mined\n";
            for( ; ; ) {
      std::string input1;
      std::cin >> input1;

      //if else library
      //words
      if (input1 == "8f434346648f6b96df89dda901c5176b10a6d83961dd3c1ac88b59b2dc327aa4") {
        std::cout << "hi\n";
      } else if (input1 == "b49f425a7e1f9cff3856329ada223f2f9d368f15a00cf48df16ca95986137fe8") {
        std::cout << "bye\n";
      } else if (input1 == "b9776d7ddf459c9ad5b0e1d6ac61e27befb5e99fd62446677600d7cacef544d0") {
          std::cout << "the\n";
        } else if (input1 == "28391d3bc64ec15cbb090426b04aa6b7649c3cc85f11230bb0105e02d15e3624") {
            std::cout << "of\n";
          } else if (input1 == "6201111b83a0cb5b0922cb37cc442b9a40e24e3b1ce100a4bb204f4c63fd2ac0") {
              std::cout << "and\n";
            } else if (input1 == "ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb") {
                std::cout << "a\n";
              } else if (input1 == "663ea1bfffe5038f3f0cf667f14c4257eff52d77ce7f2a218f72e9286616ea39") {
        std::cout << "to\n";
      } else if (input1 == "582967534d0f909d196b97f9e6921342777aea87b46fa52df165389db1fb8ccf") {
          std::cout << "in\n";
          //letters
        } else if (input1 == "3e23e8160039594a33894f6564e1b1348bbd7a0088d42c4acb73eeaed59c009d") {
          std::cout << "b\n";
        } else if (input1 == "2e7d2c03a9507ae265ecf5b5356885a53393a2029d241394997265a1a25aefc6") {
            std::cout << "c\n";
          } else if (input1 == "18ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4") {
              std::cout << "d\n";
            } else if (input1 == "3f79bb7b435b05321651daefd374cdc681dc06faa65e374e38337b88ca046dea") {
      std::cout << "e\n";
    } else if (input1 == "252f10c83610ebca1a059c0bae8255eba2f95be4d1d7bcfa89d7248a82d9f111") {
        std::cout << "f\n";
      } else if (input1 == "cd0aa9856147b6c5b4ff2b7dfee5da20aa38253099ef1b4a64aced233c9afe29") {
          std::cout << "g\n";
        } else if (input1 == "aaa9402664f1a41f40ebbc52c9993eb66aeb366602958fdfaa283b71e64db123") {
      std::cout << "h\n";
    } else if (input1 == "de7d1b721a1e0632b7cf04edf5032c8ecffa9f9a08492152b926f1a5a7e765d7") {
        std::cout << "i\n";
      } else if (input1 == "189f40034be7a199f1fa9891668ee3ab6049f82d38c68be70f596eab2e1857b7") {
          std::cout << "j\n";
        } else if (input1 == "8254c329a92850f6d539dd376f4816ee2764517da5e0235514af433164480d7a") {
            std::cout << "k\n";
          } else if (input1 == "acac86c0e609ca906f632b0e2dacccb2b77d22b0621f20ebece1a4835b93f6f0") {
              std::cout << "l\n";
            } else if (input1 == "62c66a7a5dd70c3146618063c344e531e6d4b59e379808443ce962b3abd63c5a") {
                std::cout << "m\n";
              } else if (input1 == "1b16b1df538ba12dc3f97edbb85caa7050d46c148134290feba80f8236c83db9") {
                  std::cout << "n\n";
                } else if (input1 == "65c74c15a686187bb6bbf9958f494fc6b80068034a659a9ad44991b08c58f2d2") {
                    std::cout << "o\n";
                  } else if (input1 == "148de9c5a7a44d19e56cd9ae1a554bf67847afb0c58f6e12fa29ac7ddfca9940") {
                      std::cout << "p\n";
                    } else if (input1 == "8e35c2cd3bf6641bdb0e2050b76932cbb2e6034a0ddacc1d9bea82a6ba57f7cf") {
                        std::cout << "q\n";
                      } else if (input1 == "454349e422f05297191ead13e21d3db520e5abef52055e4964b82fb213f593a1") {
                          std::cout << "r\n";
                        } else if (input1 == "043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89") {
      std::cout << "s\n";
    } else if (input1 == "e3b98a4da31a127d4bde6e43033f66ba274cab0eb7eb1c70ec41402bf6273dd8") {
        std::cout << "t\n";
      } else if (input1 == "0bfe935e70c321c7ca3afc75ce0d0ca2f98b5422e008bb31c00c6d7f1f1c0ad6") {
          std::cout << "u\n";
        } else if (input1 == "4c94485e0c21ae6c41ce1dfe7b6bfaceea5ab68e40a2476f50208e526f506080") {
            std::cout << "v\n";
          } else if (input1 == "50e721e49c013f00c62cf59f2163542a9d8df02464efeb615d31051b0fddc326") {
              std::cout << "w\n";
            } else if (input1 == "2d711642b726b04401627ca9fbac32f5c8530fb1903cc4db02258717921a4881") {
                std::cout << "x\n";
              } else if (input1 == "a1fce4363854ff888cff4b8e7875d600c2682390412a8cf79b37d0b11148b0fa") {
                  std::cout << "y\n";
                } else if (input1 == "594e519ae499312b29433b7dd8a97ff068defcba9755b6d5d00e84c524d67b06") {
                    std::cout << "z\n";
                  } else if (input1 == "fa51fd49abf67705d6a35d18218c115ff5633aec1f9ebfdc9d5d4956416f57f6") {
                    //more words
      std::cout << "is\n";
    } else if (input1 == "bb0347a468d97e98a9c00e37cebec1ab930f6f1221cae0f1fbb92b07e1900ba2") {
        std::cout << "you\n";
      } else if (input1 == "8e7fc0236af43df9340685fc16f1efe36543cc1707051220a103ad99cf69a2df") {
          std::cout << "that\n";
        } else if (input1 == "2ad8a7049d7c5511ac254f5f51fe70a046ebd884729056f0fe57f5160d467153") {
            std::cout << "it\n";
          } else if (input1 == "372f7e2fd2d01ce2a1d71dc072acbba4c6fd25a1087cd7f153f4ec0ce37e1ede") {
              std::cout << "he\n";
            } else if (input1 == "b63b99f6383ba713b57ddfc77737c5f71639fa6f4663efe60a66a8c6d114b545") {
                std::cout << "was\n";
              } else if (input1 == "10c22bcf4c768b515be4e94bcafc71bf3e8fb5f70b2584bcc8c7533217f2e7f9") {
                  std::cout << "for\n";
                } else if (input1 == "b8d31e852725afb1e26d53bab6095b2bff1749c9275be13ed1c05a56ed31ec09") {
                    std::cout << "on\n";
                  } else if (input1 == "ba78973ddcf98d4e5369f5e722d681d94f5106895e5d6cf6fa3ca8240fabdc14") {
                      std::cout << "are\n";
                    } else if (input1 == "f4bf9f7fcbedaba0392f108c59d8f4a38b3838efb64877380171b54475c2ade8") {
      std::cout << "as\n";
    } else if (input1 == "0695b563acde461fc2f8d9aebccf35c7596ac458b8d8e067c602fb7b4e5f1578") {
      std::cout << "with\n";
    } else if (input1 == "73c9c98668a34c54d131ff609d0bf129068d1b5ed3efd7cdfe753f909596456c")  {
        std::cout << "his\n";
      } else if (input1 == "151e58a831306903b282edb477bb6c4b713887cdd2b0353c84aff6f43da8e95d") {
          std::cout << "they\n";
        } else if (input1 == "de7d1b721a1e0632b7cf04edf5032c8ecffa9f9a08492152b926f1a5a7e765d7"
        ) {
      std::cout << "i\n";
    } else if (input1 == "9390298f3fb0c5b160498935d79cb139aef28e1c47358b4bbba61862b9c26e59"){
        std::cout << "no\n";
      } else if (input1 == "8a798890fe93817163b10b5f7bd2ca4d25d84c52739a645a889c173eee7d9d3d") {
          std::cout << "yes\n";
          //funny easter egg
        } else if (input1 == "no") {
          std::cout << "dont be rude :)\n";
        } else if (input1 == "d7469a66c4bb97c09aa84e8536a85f1795761f5fe01ddc8139922b6236f4397d") {
          std::cout << "Happy birthday\n https://Birthday.belizairebr25.repl.co\n";
        } else if (input1 == hash) {
          std::cout << meaning <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash1) {
          std::cout << meaning1 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash2) {
          std::cout << meaning2 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash3) {
          std::cout << meaning3 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash4) {
          std::cout << meaning4 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash5) {
          std::cout << meaning5 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash6) {
          std::cout << meaning6 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash7) {
          std::cout << meaning7 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash8) {
          std::cout << meaning8 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash9) {
          std::cout << meaning9 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash10) {
          std::cout << meaning10 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash11) {
          std::cout << meaning11 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash12) {
          std::cout << meaning12 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash13) {
          std::cout << meaning13 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash14) {
          std::cout << meaning14 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash15) {
          std::cout << meaning15 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash16) {
          std::cout << meaning16 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash17) {
          std::cout << meaning17 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash18) {
          std::cout << meaning18 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash19) {
          std::cout << meaning19 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash20) {
          std::cout << meaning20 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash21) {
          std::cout << meaning21 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash22) {
          std::cout << meaning22 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash23) {
          std::cout << meaning23 <<"\n";
        }else if (input1 == hash24) {
          std::cout << meaning24 <<"\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Enter next hash\n";
          }
          }else{
          std::cout << "Secure hash algorithm 256 hash not automatically recognized.\n  Mining, this may take a while\n";
          /*mine goes here, it measures random inputs against the user input to see if the match, encatt is used to measure and att is the attempted solution. It does not et work work yet, the below code is not mine and I am altering it in the hopes of getting it to work*/
          std::cout << "Hash not recognized\n";

         


          
    }
      
    } else {
    //no custom library option/object2
      //intilize variables and startup   

      std::string name;
      std::string securitykey = "Echoes";
      std::string usersecuritykey;
      std::cout << "Please enter the program security key\n (key = Echoes)\n";
      std::cin >> usersecuritykey;
    //security key 
      if (usersecuritykey == securitykey) {
        std::cout << "Please enter your name\n";
        std::cin >> name;
        for( ; ; ) {
      std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", Input Secure hash algorithm 256 hash to be mined\n";
      std::string inputa;
      std::cin >> inputa;

      //if else library
      //words
      if (inputa == "8f434346648f6b96df89dda901c5176b10a6d83961dd3c1ac88b59b2dc327aa4") {
        std::cout << "hi\n";
      } else if (inputa == "b49f425a7e1f9cff3856329ada223f2f9d368f15a00cf48df16ca95986137fe8") {
        std::cout << "bye\n";
      } else if (inputa == "b9776d7ddf459c9ad5b0e1d6ac61e27befb5e99fd62446677600d7cacef544d0") {
          std::cout << "the\n";
        } else if (inputa == "28391d3bc64ec15cbb090426b04aa6b7649c3cc85f11230bb0105e02d15e3624") {
            std::cout << "of\n";
          } else if (inputa == "6201111b83a0cb5b0922cb37cc442b9a40e24e3b1ce100a4bb204f4c63fd2ac0") {
              std::cout << "and\n";
            } else if (inputa == "ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb") {
                std::cout << "a\n";
              } else if (inputa == "663ea1bfffe5038f3f0cf667f14c4257eff52d77ce7f2a218f72e9286616ea39") {
        std::cout << "to\n";
      } else if (inputa == "582967534d0f909d196b97f9e6921342777aea87b46fa52df165389db1fb8ccf") {
          std::cout << "in\n";
          //letters
        } else if (inputa == "3e23e8160039594a33894f6564e1b1348bbd7a0088d42c4acb73eeaed59c009d") {
          std::cout << "b\n";
        } else if (inputa == "2e7d2c03a9507ae265ecf5b5356885a53393a2029d241394997265a1a25aefc6") {
            std::cout << "c\n";
          } else if (inputa == "18ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4") {
              std::cout << "d\n";
            } else if (inputa == "3f79bb7b435b05321651daefd374cdc681dc06faa65e374e38337b88ca046dea") {
      std::cout << "e\n";
    } else if (inputa == "252f10c83610ebca1a059c0bae8255eba2f95be4d1d7bcfa89d7248a82d9f111") {
        std::cout << "f\n";
      } else if (inputa == "cd0aa9856147b6c5b4ff2b7dfee5da20aa38253099ef1b4a64aced233c9afe29") {
          std::cout << "g\n";
        } else if (inputa == "aaa9402664f1a41f40ebbc52c9993eb66aeb366602958fdfaa283b71e64db123") {
      std::cout << "h\n";
    } else if (inputa == "de7d1b721a1e0632b7cf04edf5032c8ecffa9f9a08492152b926f1a5a7e765d7") {
        std::cout << "i\n";
      } else if (inputa == "189f40034be7a199f1fa9891668ee3ab6049f82d38c68be70f596eab2e1857b7") {
          std::cout << "j\n";
        } else if (inputa == "8254c329a92850f6d539dd376f4816ee2764517da5e0235514af433164480d7a") {
            std::cout << "k\n";
          } else if (inputa == "acac86c0e609ca906f632b0e2dacccb2b77d22b0621f20ebece1a4835b93f6f0") {
              std::cout << "l\n";
            } else if (inputa == "62c66a7a5dd70c3146618063c344e531e6d4b59e379808443ce962b3abd63c5a") {
                std::cout << "m\n";
              } else if (inputa == "1b16b1df538ba12dc3f97edbb85caa7050d46c148134290feba80f8236c83db9") {
                  std::cout << "n\n";
                } else if (inputa == "65c74c15a686187bb6bbf9958f494fc6b80068034a659a9ad44991b08c58f2d2") {
                    std::cout << "o\n";
                  } else if (inputa == "148de9c5a7a44d19e56cd9ae1a554bf67847afb0c58f6e12fa29ac7ddfca9940") {
                      std::cout << "p\n";
                    } else if (inputa == "8e35c2cd3bf6641bdb0e2050b76932cbb2e6034a0ddacc1d9bea82a6ba57f7cf") {
                        std::cout << "q\n";
                      } else if (inputa == "454349e422f05297191ead13e21d3db520e5abef52055e4964b82fb213f593a1") {
                          std::cout << "r\n";
                        } else if (inputa == "043a718774c572bd8a25adbeb1bfcd5c0256ae11cecf9f9c3f925d0e52beaf89") {
      std::cout << "s\n";
    } else if (inputa == "e3b98a4da31a127d4bde6e43033f66ba274cab0eb7eb1c70ec41402bf6273dd8") {
        std::cout << "t\n";
      } else if (inputa == "0bfe935e70c321c7ca3afc75ce0d0ca2f98b5422e008bb31c00c6d7f1f1c0ad6") {
          std::cout << "u\n";
        } else if (inputa == "4c94485e0c21ae6c41ce1dfe7b6bfaceea5ab68e40a2476f50208e526f506080") {
            std::cout << "v\n";
          } else if (inputa == "50e721e49c013f00c62cf59f2163542a9d8df02464efeb615d31051b0fddc326") {
              std::cout << "w\n";
            } else if (inputa == "2d711642b726b04401627ca9fbac32f5c8530fb1903cc4db02258717921a4881") {
                std::cout << "x\n";
              } else if (inputa == "a1fce4363854ff888cff4b8e7875d600c2682390412a8cf79b37d0b11148b0fa") {
                  std::cout << "y\n";
                } else if (inputa == "594e519ae499312b29433b7dd8a97ff068defcba9755b6d5d00e84c524d67b06") {
                    std::cout << "z\n";
                  } else if (inputa == "fa51fd49abf67705d6a35d18218c115ff5633aec1f9ebfdc9d5d4956416f57f6") {
                    //more words
      std::cout << "is\n";
    } else if (inputa == "bb0347a468d97e98a9c00e37cebec1ab930f6f1221cae0f1fbb92b07e1900ba2") {
        std::cout << "you\n";
      } else if (inputa == "8e7fc0236af43df9340685fc16f1efe36543cc1707051220a103ad99cf69a2df") {
          std::cout << "that\n";
        } else if (inputa == "2ad8a7049d7c5511ac254f5f51fe70a046ebd884729056f0fe57f5160d467153") {
            std::cout << "it\n";
          } else if (inputa == "372f7e2fd2d01ce2a1d71dc072acbba4c6fd25a1087cd7f153f4ec0ce37e1ede") {
              std::cout << "he\n";
            } else if (inputa == "b63b99f6383ba713b57ddfc77737c5f71639fa6f4663efe60a66a8c6d114b545") {
                std::cout << "was\n";
              } else if (inputa == "10c22bcf4c768b515be4e94bcafc71bf3e8fb5f70b2584bcc8c7533217f2e7f9") {
                  std::cout << "for\n";
                } else if (inputa == "b8d31e852725afb1e26d53bab6095b2bff1749c9275be13ed1c05a56ed31ec09") {
                    std::cout << "on\n";
                  } else if (inputa == "ba78973ddcf98d4e5369f5e722d681d94f5106895e5d6cf6fa3ca8240fabdc14") {
                      std::cout << "are\n";
                    } else if (inputa == "f4bf9f7fcbedaba0392f108c59d8f4a38b3838efb64877380171b54475c2ade8") {
      std::cout << "as\n";
    } else if (inputa == "0695b563acde461fc2f8d9aebccf35c7596ac458b8d8e067c602fb7b4e5f1578") {
      std::cout << "with\n";
    } else if (inputa == "73c9c98668a34c54d131ff609d0bf129068d1b5ed3efd7cdfe753f909596456c")  {
        std::cout << "his\n";
      } else if (inputa == "151e58a831306903b282edb477bb6c4b713887cdd2b0353c84aff6f43da8e95d") {
          std::cout << "they\n";
        } else if (inputa == "de7d1b721a1e0632b7cf04edf5032c8ecffa9f9a08492152b926f1a5a7e765d7"
        ) {
      std::cout << "i\n";
    } else if (inputa == "9390298f3fb0c5b160498935d79cb139aef28e1c47358b4bbba61862b9c26e59"){
        std::cout << "no\n";
      } else if (inputa == "8a798890fe93817163b10b5f7bd2ca4d25d84c52739a645a889c173eee7d9d3d") {
          std::cout << "yes\n";
          //funny easter egg
        } else if (inputa == "no") {
          std::cout << "dont be rude :)\n";
        } else if (inputa == "d7469a66c4bb97c09aa84e8536a85f1795761f5fe01ddc8139922b6236f4397d") {
          std::cout << "Happy birthday\n https://Birthday.belizairebr25.repl.co\n";
          }else{
          std::cout << "Secure hash algorithm 256 hash not automatically recognized\n  Mining, this may take a while\n";
          /*mine goes here, it measures random inputs against the user input to see if the match, encatt is used to measure and att is the attempted solution. It does not et work work yet, the below code is not mine and I am altering it in the hopes of getting it to work*/
          std::cout <<"'" << inputa << "' not recognized\n";
          /*


    static const char alphanum[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

    char genRandom()  // Random string generator function.
    {

        return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
    }

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for(int z=0; z < 21; z++)
        {
            cout << "tried:" << genRandom();
        }
        
        return 117;
    }

        if (input == encatt) {
          std::cout << "hash means" << att;
        }
        */
         




    }
    }
        } else {
      std::cout << "invalid key, please try again\n";

        }
    }
    }
```

That is the cpp and here is the existing sqlite, it is very little and does not do much

```
    --Table Creation:

    CREATE TABLE SHA ( value TEXT, hash BLOB, id DOUBLE);
    --Insert Data:
    --D1: 6/14
    INSERT INTO SHA (value, id, hash)
    VALUES ("test", 1, "532eaabd9574880dbf76b9b8cc00832c20a6ec113d682299550d7a6e0f345e25");

    --Display:
    SELECT * FROM SHA;
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Note: When you find yourself making sequentially named or numbered variables, what you're trying to express will probably be simpler to write with an array.

Comment: Thanks I'll try converting it to an array.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll find few people with the time to read through and comment on a question containing more than 500 lines of code.  Even when your question is "How do I reduce this code to something manageable?" I'd offer more than generalities up, but my SQL is weak and I have yet to use SQLLite.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are trying to do is not possible. You have several syntax errors in your code. I suggest using a different program.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked, and should not be posted as one. When you earn the comment privilege, you'll be able to leave comments like this on the original question instead, which would be the appropriate place for this content. Until you've earned that privilege, however, you cannot use the answer space instead.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way I can add a database in cpp that is separate from the program allowing it not to be rewritten each time the program is run? If not what language could I use to do this? I do, however agree that this is not a valid answer to my question. I am quite sure there must be some way to connect these backend languages.